# Copy and rename aar generated from gradle android

Tags: android, gradle, aar

In my library module I want to copy and rename the aar file to different path
Below code is used

```
ext {
    version = 'P-1.1.6'
    name = 'Player'
}
defaultConfig {
    missingDimensionStrategy "exoplayerversion", "Exo_2_13_3", "Exo_2_18_1"
    missingDimensionStrategy "playserviceversion", "PlayService_16_0_0", "PlayService_21_0_1"
    buildConfigField "String", "LIBRARY_VERSION", "\"${version}\""
}
libraryVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.all { output ->
        def outputFile = output.outputFile
        if (outputFile != null && outputFile.name.endsWith('.aar')) {
            if (outputFile.name.contains("debug"))
                outputFileName = new File("../../../../releases/${version}", "${name}-${version}-debug.aar")
            else outputFileName = new File("../../../../releases/${version}", "${name}-${version}-release.aar")
        }
        variant.assemble.doLast {
            if (variant.mappingFile != null) {
                copy {
                    from variant.mappingFile
                    into outputFile.parent
                    rename { String fileName ->
                        "../../../../releases/${version}/mapping.txt"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The `aar` file is being copied but name isn't correct
I am getting the aar name as `Exo_2_18_1-PlayService_16_0_0-debug-P-1.1.6-debug.aar` while it should be `Player-P-1.1.6-debug.aar`

Answer (score 0):

Have to use `project.name`

```
 outputFileName = new File("../../../../releases/${version}", "${project.name}-${version}-debug.aar")
```